# How to register my altbeacon to Google acoount?

Tags: android-studio, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I want to register altbeacon's uuid or information to a Google account.
So when I select altbeacon what I detected, I can communicate with beacon's owner.

Can I change uuid or add something like tag for connecting account?
(I want code or library for that...T.T)

Answer (score 0):

Your description is kind of incomplete. But if you store beacons information and want find out the owner, the simplest solution is to use a API with your app(check APISPark, its free). When a beacon is detected, make a HTPP GET call to the API server which will query the database for a specific resource(in your case the owners information associated with the beacon). Parse the JSON response in your android app and you are done. Once you have the owner's information you can further process it with [google contact api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) to send email and so on.